# How to automatically log out a user after period of time?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to website creations, However I have made a website and would like display who is Online, and who is Offline. with the best method, and Log them out, if they are inactive for so long. As of current, When someone logs in it updates the column `"online"` to `"1"`. Then when someone logs out, it will update `"online"` to `"0"`.

I also do have a timestamp in the database which tells me when they logged in, and when the logged out. (and as I said, Im a bit new to all this), as someone has said, why should i need both `"online"` and `"login_time"`. I just thought it may be easier. This is the code I have...

Login.php:

```
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id (true);
    $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    $_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
    mysql_query("update users set online='0' where login_time >= 60");
    mysql_query("update users set online='1' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
               }
      header("Location: home.php");
     }
```

Would there be a better way to do this? and include an easier method to update someone as offline after 5 mins of inactivity?

Comment: `WHERE login_time = > 60”);` the syntax is `>=` and not the other way around. Your question's unclear btw. You need to post actual syntax etc.

Comment: Thank You, This worked perfectly to log other inactive users out, when someone else logs in. however, would there be an easier way to do this without the use of someone else logging in to update the status?

Comment: There is a lot to consider here like what is inactive loading pages or clicking? I would suggest JS or jQuery. You can do this with a cookie or more likely the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case something goes wrong, try to tie down the problem by debugging it. First, try to run your command in a mySQL console:

```
mysql> UPDATE users set online='0' WHERE login_time = > 60;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '> 60' at line 1
```

The correct syntax for greater-than is >= (the lower/greater always comes first).

`login_time >= 60` would also require you to update the time every second manually which creates a high database load. Your UPDATE command would need to be run once a second to catch all users.

You should consider storing and matching the login (or last action) datetime instead:

On Login:

```
UPDATE users SET login_time=NOW() WHERE id=?
```

Check if a user is still online:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 minute)
```

See the mySQL documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add for more about DATE_SUB and INTERVAL.

PS: [The PHP manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) *This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.* about *mysql_query*.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i have now. Would this work? 
  $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
  $_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 minute"));
  mysql_query("update users set online='1' where id='$id'")

Comment: It would probably run without throwing an error, but the query to select all logged in users doesn't make sense. Working time-based won't need a "online" column in the users table.

Comment: Im quite new to all this and trying to figure it out. I basicly just want to know when someone is online or offline so on my members page, it would display them either being online, or offline, from the "online" column in the database. but i need to know how to auto-update the database, to set them as "0" when they are inactive for a period of time, to display they are no longer active.

Comment: The idea is to not update the database at all (each DB update is expensive in terms of database resources). Just store the date&time of the login or (better) last action and treat the user as offline if this timestamp is older than 5 minutes.

Comment: is there a way then, i could have my UPDATE command run once, every time they go to a new page, to keep the time in the database updated? otherwise, it would say they are inactive after the 5 mins because the database hasn't been updated?

Comment: Sure, run the UPDATE on every page access. I don't know your scripts, but most frameworks have a "before" or "auto" section which runs on every request.

Comment: My script is basic, and only have login.php, member.php, home.php, index.php, logout.php and db.php, im just learning new code. thank you for your help :)

Comment: You should have some file which is included in every script (for connecting the database, doing common stuff, etc.) Put your UPDATE into that file.
Would be great if you could accept the answer if it has been helpful.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, However my UPDATE code doesn't work on any pages, it doesn't update the time. Where would i be going wrong? 
<php include 'connect.php';
$sql = "UPDATE users SET login_time=NOW() WHERE id=$id";
?>